# jQuery Multiple Autocomplete with c#

Tags: c#, jquery, autocomplete

I'm implementing multiple autocomplete using jQuery UI. Also I'm using webservice to pass values. I check jQuery UI demo for multiple autocomplete and using exact same code and it's working until the first autocomplete and adds a "," at the end.

But here I'm stuck, It's not searching for the next autocomplete. Well I didn't add a part of the code from the demo, which I don't know where it suppose to go. If someone could help me please.

### Heare isthe My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        function split(val) {
            return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }
        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }

        $(".tb")

        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })

        .autocomplete({

            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "EmployeeList.asmx/FetchEmailList",
                    data: "{ 'mail': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //term: extractLast(request.term),
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item.Email
                            }
                        }))
                    },

                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },

            search: function () {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast(this.value);
                alert(term);
                if (term.length < 2) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function () {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                alert(terms);
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join(", ");
                return false;
            } //,

            //minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script>
```

### Here is the code I'm missing from jQuery UI demo

```
.autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON( "search.php", {
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
            },
```

I don't know where to add this code:
**term: extractLast( request.term )**
here is the link for entire code [Demo Code link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
data: "{ 'mail': '" + request.term + "' }"
```

with

```
 data: "{ 'mail': '" + extractLast(request.term) + "' }"
```

this should work but i didn't like much the way you encode JSON, may create problems with quotes etc.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! By the way is there any suggestion that you have to encode JSON?

Comment: mmm, something like JSON.stringify({mail: extractLast(request.term)}), but make sure you include JSON2.js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js as older browsers may not support JSON encoding.